# data html5 and jquery fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done googling and still can't find a solution to my basic question.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="medical_txt" name="medical_txt" data_medical-stat="yes" >
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#medical_txt").blur(function(){
        console.log(this);
        var data_var = jQuery(this).data('medical-stat');
        var attr_var = jQuery(this).attr('data_medical-stat');
        alert(data_var);
        alert(attr_var);
        var second_try=$('#medical_txt').data('medical-stat');          
        alert("second_try:"+second_try);
    });
});
```

output =>  `undefined, yes , undefined`

Can some one help me out what went wrong with the first and last ?

Comment: try `data-medical-stat`

Comment: @Adarsh whose answer helped you?

Comment: @Freelancer both yogi and Raibaz were spot on and they were so quick on that I didn't notice whom post did I read first. either way both were stating the same point. Thank you guys.. :-)

Comment: @Adarsh I asked because person who has helped you has put some efforts in that, so they needs to get upvote. But you dont have right to vote. Hence i given them upvotes. Accept Raibaz's answer by ticking check near it. :)

Comment: @Freelancer Done mate!!.. :-) I tried as and when it worked.. Butstack overflow don't allow u to accept the answer within 10 min of posting of question.. :)
btw can u please upvote Raibaz answer as I don't have the reputaion to upvote??

Comment: @Adarsh Yeah. I know that. This is because everyone should get what he deservs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data attributes are specified as `data-`, not `data_`, that's why you're getting undefined with `.data` but you're getting the result if you use the exact attribute name and `.attr`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using data() in wrong way.

Before fetching make sure you've stored object you're trying to fetch like .data('medical-stat', { ... }) then you can read it like this .data('medical-stat') -> will return {...}